# Google OAuth2 – 400 Bad request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to set up Google Identity. I've configured my OAuth2 Client IDs by adding in the Google Cloud Console:

1. Authorized origins: `http://localhost`, `http://localhost:3000`, `https://my-app.herokuapp.com`
2. Authorized redirect URIs: `http://localhost`, `http://localhost:3000`, `https://my-app.herokuapp.com`

The setup is working nice on localhost, yet it's showing a white screen in the popup when I try to access it from `https://my-app.herokuapp.com`.
All I can see in the popup console is a failing `400` `GET` request to:

```
https://accounts.google.com/gsi/button?type=standard&theme=outline&size=large&text=Sign in with Google&shape=pill&logo_alignment=left&width=undefined&client_id=my-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com&iframe_id=some-iframeid&as=some-as&hl=en-US
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Please share the complete error message and the logs from the Cloud Identity.

Comment: It needed time to "catch" the domain :)